# The Assemble 2 Images PNG Reponsive Not Move

Tags: html, css

I have the 2 image png is the image-1.png and the image-2.png.

In the HTML, I want to assembly the 2 image png it. The image-1.png top and the image-2.png bottom. When I edit CSS done and try responsive, and the apparent space between the 2 images.

How to fix it, I only want to use the image png and assembly they, but when responsive always the position between 2 images is not to move.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `img{ display: block; }` should fix your issue.